# "Select all" in all textboxes

Tags: c#

```
private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.SelectAll();
        }
```

This works but I have 6 textBoxes.  Is there any easier way instead of adding event listeners for each and every textbox? Or a shorthand or something?

Thanks.

Comment: I think your looking for a property to set but I don't think there is one. The only way I can think of is to add events to the textbox.OnClick to all call the same method. Then use sender.SelectAll();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the same event handler to each and have `((TextBox)sender).SelectAll()` to ensure the one that is clicked on is highlighted.

If you're looking for something more generic create a derived class of TextBox containing the same.